# Mongoose and the autoReconnect option conundrum

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm really confused with mongoose `autoReconnect` option inside `mongoose.connect` methods. My problem is that my server may start before database connection is ready, so I have to handle this at the start of my server code. Well, let me explain what I have until now:

First, I tried the documented way:

```
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', () => console.log('database connected'));
mongoose.connect(dbUri, { autoReconnect: true });
```

It kinda works, (mongo console shows: `I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52896 #1 (1 connection now open)`) but it never calls the `open` callback. What is really weird about this solution though is that `db.readyState` never become `1` (which I suppose it's the reason the callback is never called).

After that, I searched for a solution and found several of them, including those [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226472/mongoose-autoreconnect-option), and on [github](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5169). To sum up them, here it is the basic solution:

```
function connect() {
    mongoose.connect(dbUri, { autoReconnect: true });
}

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', () => console.log('database connected'));

db.on('error', () => {
    console.log('database connection error');
    mongoose.disconnect();
});

db.on('disconnected', () => {
    console.log('database disconnected.');
    connect();
});

connect();
```

Again, this solution kida works too, but this time, every call to `connect()` method creates a new connection, so my mongo console show something like:

```
I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52896 #5 (35 connections now open)
I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52896 #6 (36 connections now open)
I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52896 #7 (37 connections now open)
...
```

Playing around I find out that's because of the `autoReconnect` option. If i set it to false (which is really not recommended by the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options)), a single connection is made when database is ready. But I think that `autoReconnect` means to do it not just when the connection is made, but while it's active through the execution of the application.

So, what am I missing here? Is there something that I should be doing in the first example? Do I keep `autoReconnect` and ignore the multiple connection thing? Or there is another solution I didn't find?

- Node: 8.9.0
- MongoDB: 3.6.5
- Mongoose: 5.0.11