# MongoDB/Mongoose unhandled error on disconnect - why isn't it firing on('error') event?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, error-handling, reconnect

I'm connecting to a MongoDB database using the mongoose library.

After running `mongoose.connect()` I'm creating a `mongoose.connection.on('error')` handler.

After the app starts, I stop the MongoDB service to simulate a 'lost-connection event'.  The script outputs:

```
events.js:196
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ...
```

and my app crashes.

The on('error') handler never executes. Why not? Isn't that the point of this event handler: to handle errors that the MongoDB connection throws, to avoid the app crashing?

Expected behavior: if the MongoDB connection is lost, the app attempts to reconnect indefinitely.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my full connection code:

```
function dbConnect() {
// Establish MongoDB connection
    logger.debug(`Connecting to MongoDB database ${process.env.DB_SERVER}:${process.env.DB_PORT} database ${process.env.DB_DATABASE}...`)

    // Set up connection string
    const db_uri = `mongodb://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@${process.env.DB_SERVER}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_AUTH_DATABASE}`

    // Initiate connection:
    mongoose.connect(db_uri, { 
        dbName: process.env.DB_DATABASE,        // Connect to the specified database
        useNewUrlParser: true,                  // Use new settings
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        autoIndex: process.env.DB_AUTO_INDEX,   // Autoindex
        reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,       // Keep retrying forever (thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/39684734/1502289 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/41923785/1502289)
        reconnectInterval: 5000,                // Time to wait between reconnection attempts
    })
    .then(() => {
        logger.debug("MongoDB successful connection")
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        logger.debug("MongoDB connection error", err)
    })

    const db = mongoose.connection

    // Set up database event handlers:
    db.on('error', function(err) { logger.error("Unable to connect to database.  Error: " + err) } )

    db.once('open', function() { 
        logger.debug('Mongoose database connection established.')

        // Load common properties from database:

        // ... [snip]

    })

    db.on('disconnected', function() {
        logger.error('MongoDB disconnected.  Attempting to reconnect...')
    })

    db.on('reconnected', function() { logger.debug('Mongoose reconnected.')})
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Mongoose 5.8.7, driver 3.5.0. mongo 3.6.9. I get  "MongoDB disconnected.  Attempting to reconnect...", followed by "Mongoose reconnected" few minutes later when I restored connection to the db.

Comment: So I wonder what am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI it crashed immediately when I stopped mongodb, not when I ran the next query.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but there is nothing wrong in the code you posted. Well, there are few things, but they are not related. If you do reproduce it with exact code in the question then it must be related to the specific versions. It's more likely that the unhandled error comes from something you didn't include in the question.

Comment: Ok thanks. As stated the error is thrown immediately upon stopping Mongodb service.

Comment: Also would you be willing to share the unrelated problems you referenced in this code? I'm still a novice on nodejs and mongodb and would welcome opportunities to improve. Thanks.

Comment: Please read https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options for `reconnectTries` - it makes no sense when used with "useUnifiedTopology: true"