# Unhandled promise rejection warning connecting to mongoDB with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so I have this code (simplified a bit) to connect to a database, I have `DATABASE_URL` wrong on purpose so I get an error. But what I do not understand is the reason for which I am getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

Any ideas?

cheers!

```
try {
    startServer();
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}




async function startServer () {
    try {
        await connectToDatabase;
    } catch ( err ) {
        throw err;
    }
}

const connectToDatabase = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoose.connect(
        process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        }
    );
    const database = mongoose.connection;
    database.on(
        'error',
        err => reject(err)
    );
    database.once(
        'open',
        () => {
            console.log('Connected to database...');
            resolve(database);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: startServer is an async function, in your try block you are not awaiting it.

Comment: Also, here `await connectToDatabase;` did you missed calling the function first using `connectToDatabase()` ?

Comment: @Kevin.a so if I got you right, you meant I have to wrap my first try catch in another async function in order to be able to use await before `startServer()`. In that case wouldn't I have another unhandled promise (the one returned by the added async function)?

Comment: @Kevin.a `connectToDatabase` is a promise not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mongoose.connect` returns a promise](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#error-handling).

So you need to change:

```js
  const connectToDatabase = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoose.connect(
      process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
      }
    )
      .then(() => {
        const database = mongoose.connection
       
        database.on('error', err => {
          logError(err);
        });
        database.once(
          'open',
          () => {
            console.log('Connected to database...')
            resolve(database)
          }
        )
      })
      .catch(reject)
  })
```

You should improve this code:

```
        database.on('error', err => {
          logError(err);
        });
```

because this event is triggered whenever there is an error after the connection has been established, like a disconnection.

So you can't `reject` a promise that has been already `resolve`d with the `open` event.
You should [configure the reconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17093472/3309466)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are perfectly right about the last statement, since the error can occur after the promise has been resolved. So I should try to handle the future errors if any should happen. But I am curious, in this particular case the promise will never resolve since `DATABASE_URL` is wrong.
And besides that, now that I am using another catch after `mongoose.connect()` promise, I am still getting the same old unhandled promise warning.

Comment: Did you add the `.catch(reject)` too? It is at the end, after the `then`

Comment: Actually the catch on the connect method did the job, I didn't particularly use your exact approach, but I could solve the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By doing this: `const connectToDatabase = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...` you are building a `Promise` on **top level**, before awaiting for it in the `startServer`.
It's an equivalent of doing this:

```js
// Top level Promise rejection
Promise.reject('error');
```

The rest of the code still works because `await` works on a already-resolved `Promise` (also, maybe the `Promise` has not resolved yet when awaited) but you should build the `Promise` inside a `function` instead:

```
try {
    startServer();
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}

async function startServer () {
    try {
        await connectToDatabase();
    } catch ( err ) {
        throw err;
    }
}

function connectToDatabase() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mongoose.connect(
            process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });
        const database = mongoose.connection;
        database.on(
            'error',
            err => reject(err));
        database.once(
            'open',
            () => {
            console.log('Connected to database...');
            resolve(database);
        });
    });
}
```

With this, you get a reference on the `new Promise` **only** in `startServer` immediately after it is created, **then** it resolves or rejects and the possible rejection is caught and doesn't bubble up to the top level.